# Add values of a column depending on another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Ok, let me explain shortly what I want to do.

I have on column A a list of names with a list of values on column B. I already have a datalist with names too. I want to add all the values of B if the corresponding name in column A is in my list.

Let's say my list is named List and have 3 values: "John","Scott","Gary"

On column A, I have: "John", "Peter", "Daniel", "Scott"
On column B, I have: 1,2,3,4

Since both John and Scott are on my List, I would like to add up 1+4 to have 5.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A;List;B:B))`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible...

In the below example I have done a VLookup for each Name in the list and then a SUM on the results.

```
  A     B
Mike    1
Dave    2
Scott   3
Harry   4

  C     D
Dave    =VLOOKUP(C2,A1:B4,2,FALSE)
Harry   =VLOOKUP(C3,A1:B4,2,FALSE)
    =SUM(D2:D3)
```

Comment: Well, in the reality the list of name is dynamic, I don't know how many names I actually have (but it's around 50) so this solution wouldn't really fit. However, @XOR LX's answer seems to work.